# Are input variables to Terraform included in the state file or stored otherwise?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm using a Terraform file to pass in an SSH key using a [Terraform variable](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html) when I run `terraform apply`.  The key is not included in the main.tf file.

I run the Terraform file and the prompt will ask for my file then the file is put on my Google Cloud Compute instance.

From a security standpoint, it would be a risk to store this SSH key in the autogenerated files such as the `d.terraform.lock.hcl`.

Will input variables supplied at runtime be stored in these files?

Edit: I know that I can just search for the input in the .tfstate file but I want to make sure the hashes in the lock file aren't somehow reverse engineerable.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] of what you've done so far please? That way someone would be able to tell you definitively whether the key is stored in Terraform's state file. In general though you should treat your state files as containing secrets so must be secured properly. If you can't do that for some reason it might be worth explaining why that's the case for your specific case.

Comment: Would using the GCP Secret Manager be an option for your use case? If so you could potentially use a data block to retrieve the secret. I can't talk about the security/safety with this but just wanted to give an additional option to you.